# How to view multiple taxonomy terms content on same page?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, navigation

In Drupal 6, it was possible to view links like:

`taxonomy/term/1,2`,

`taxonomy/term/1+2`,

`taxonomy/term/2/2` or `taxonomy/term/2/all` which would list multiple taxonomy terms on single page (showing term and its children).

**Issue:** I know, this is [not default possible in Drupal 7](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/organizing-content-with-taxonomies/about-taxonomies), and [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/organizing-content-with-taxonomies/using-taxonomy-urls-to-display-sets-of-content) also. This applies to in Drupal 8 too.

**What I want?** I'm `using Drupal 8`. I'd like to be able to link multiple taxonomy terms by a single link (e.g. in menu; i.e. to get multiple taxonomy terms to single node). I don't like to create special view to each combination. I need (I have rich taxonomy, so that I'd like to avoid dozens of views).

Answer (score 0):

I did this successfully myself by:

- choosing "Structure>content types",
- clicking 'manage fields' on the content type with the taxonomy term link,
- selecting 'edit' on the taxonomy field.

Now you can change the settings by selecting the field settings tab.
Simply change ' Allowed number of values ' to the desired number.

Hope this works for you. Ruud

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm asking for something different. Or I misunderstood Your answer. I don't need to attach multiple taxonomy terms to a node. What I need: `/taxonomy/term/1` lists content of 1st category on a page. `/taxonomy/term/2` lists content of 2nd category on page. I wish to list both categories on a single page (merge of categories 1 and 2) - in Drupal 6 it was done by `/taxonomy/term/1+2`. This apparently does not work in Drupal 8. I can do it with views, but such simple link (in menu and so) would be better solution for me.

Comment: oh. I see. I misunderstood the question. Sorry for that. I